# Reporting query blocks other query, but ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED SET

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

On MySQL 5.7.11 running on Amazon RDS with InnoDB

I have a fairly heavy reporting query that takes about 3 minutes to run. During this time I can't access my reporting screen, which reads some min and max dates from one of the tables that is included in the report.

I would have thought by setting "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED" read-only queries would not affect each other at all? I have this set both at session level and my param group on RDS

Is there anything I'm missing?

**SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS**

http://pastebin.com/XvU1AdNM

**show create table ...**

auto_increment number indicate rough row counts

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `txn_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `txn_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_rmn` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `customer_no` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `aggregator_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_amount` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `incoming_commission` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `mmplt_txn_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `txn_category` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `circle` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `retailer_commission` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `total_commission` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `net_revenue` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `ad_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_commission` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `md_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `md_commission` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnf_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnf_commission` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `md_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnf_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `txnId` (`txn_id`),
  KEY `IDX_723705D193CB796C` (`file_id`),
  KEY `date_idx` (`txn_date`),
  KEY `user_idx` (`user_id`),
  KEY `cnf_idx` (`cnf_id`),
  KEY `md_idx` (`md_id`),
  KEY `ad_idx` (`ad_id`),
  KEY `user_rmn_idx` (`user_rmn`),
  KEY `trans_amount_idx` (`trans_amount`),
  KEY `incoming_commission_idx` (`incoming_commission`),
  KEY `retailer_commission_idx` (`retailer_commission`),
  KEY `ad_commission_idx` (`ad_commission`),
  KEY `md_commission_idx` (`md_commission`),
  KEY `cnf_commission_idx` (`cnf_commission`),
  KEY `cnf_date_idx` (`txn_date`,`cnf_id`),
  KEY `md_date_idx` (`txn_date`,`md_id`),
  KEY `ad_date_idx` (`txn_date`,`ad_id`),
  KEY `user_rmn_date_idx` (`txn_date`,`user_rmn`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_723705D193CB796C` FOREIGN KEY (`file_id`) REFERENCES `file_to_sync` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11370410 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `operator` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_low_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_medium_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_high_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_D7A6A781B596C062` (`category_low_id`),
  KEY `IDX_D7A6A78125326495` (`category_medium_id`),
  KEY `IDX_D7A6A7818196AB83` (`category_high_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D7A6A78125326495` FOREIGN KEY (`category_medium_id`) REFERENCES `operator_category_medium` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D7A6A7818196AB83` FOREIGN KEY (`category_high_id`) REFERENCES `operator_category_high` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D7A6A781B596C062` FOREIGN KEY (`category_low_id`) REFERENCES `operator_category_low` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `operator` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_low_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_medium_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_high_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_D7A6A781B596C062` (`category_low_id`),
  KEY `IDX_D7A6A78125326495` (`category_medium_id`),
  KEY `IDX_D7A6A7818196AB83` (`category_high_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D7A6A78125326495` FOREIGN KEY (`category_medium_id`) REFERENCES `operator_category_medium` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D7A6A7818196AB83` FOREIGN KEY (`category_high_id`) REFERENCES `operator_category_high` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D7A6A781B596C062` FOREIGN KEY (`category_low_id`) REFERENCES `operator_category_low` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `operator_category_medium` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `operator_category_high` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `depositor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `depositor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `deposited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `details` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `netsuite_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `depositor_idx` (`depositor_id`),
  KEY `netsuite_id_idx` (`netsuite_id`),
  KEY `deposited_idx` (`deposited`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62650 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Queries**

```
DROP temporary TABLE IF EXISTS `depositor_type`;

CREATE temporary TABLE `depositor_type` (
  `depositor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  amount decimal(20,4) NULL,
  count_deposit int(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (depositor_id, type),
  KEY type_idx (type),
  KEY amount_idx (amount)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into depositor_type (type, depositor_id )  select distinct 'u',user_rmn as depositor_id from transaction where txn_date between :from and :to and user_rmn is not null  union DISTINCT  select distinct 'a',ad_id as depositor_id from transaction where txn_date between :from and :to  and ad_id is not null union DISTINCT  select distinct 'm',md_id as depositor_id from transaction where txn_date between :from and :to  and md_id is not null union DISTINCT  select distinct 'c',cnf_id as depositor_id from transaction where txn_date between :from and :to  and cnf_id is not null;

update depositor_type set  amount=(select sum(amount) from depositor d where d.depositor_id=depositor_type.depositor_id),  count_deposit=(select count(amount) from depositor d where d.depositor_id=depositor_type.depositor_id) ;

DROP  TABLE IF EXISTS `9bf92fsums`;
CREATE TABLE `9bf92fsums` (  `cnf_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                             `md_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                             `ad_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                             `user_rmn` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                             `operator_id` int(11) not null,
                             `trans_amount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
                             `incoming_commission` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
                             `retailer_commission` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
                             `ad_commission` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
                             `md_commission` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
                             `cnf_commission` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
                             `count_trans` int(11) not null,

  PRIMARY KEY (`cnf_id`,`md_id`,`ad_id`,`user_rmn`, `operator_id`),
  KEY `md_id_idx` (`cnf_id`),
  KEY `ad_id_idx` (`ad_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_rmn_idx` (`user_rmn`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `operator_id_idx` (`operator_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into 9bf92fsums select distinct coalesce(cnf_id,0), coalesce(md_id,0), coalesce(ad_id,0), coalesce(user_rmn,0), operator_id,  sum(trans_amount), sum(incoming_commission) as incoming_commission, sum(retailer_commission) as retailer_commission,  sum(ad_commission) as ad_commission, sum(md_commission) as md_commission, sum(cnf_commission), count(txn_id) as count_trans from transaction  where txn_date between :from and :to  group by coalesce(cnf_id,0), coalesce(md_id,0), coalesce(ad_id,0), coalesce(user_rmn,0), operator_id

select 'User' as type, user_rmn as phone, t.amount,  sum(trans_amount), sum(incoming_commission) as incoming_commission, sum(retailer_commission) as retailer_commission,  sum(ad_commission) as ad_commission, sum(md_commission) as md_commission, sum(cnf_commission), sum(count_deposit) as cnt_depositors, sum(count_trans) as count_trans, och.name as operator_category_high, ocm.name as operator_category_medium, ocl.name as operator_category_low from 9bf92fsums s      inner join depositor_type t on s.user_rmn=t.depositor_id and t.type='u'      inner join operator o on s.operator_id=o.id      left join operator_category_high och on (o.category_high_id=och.id)     left join operator_category_medium ocm on (o.category_medium_id=ocm.id)     left join operator_category_low ocl on (o.category_low_id=ocl.id) where t.amount > 0  group by user_rmn, och.name, ocm.name, ocl.name

select 'AD' as type, ad_id as phone, t.amount,  sum(trans_amount), sum(incoming_commission) as incoming_commission, sum(retailer_commission) as retailer_commission,  sum(ad_commission) as ad_commission, sum(md_commission) as md_commission, sum(cnf_commission), sum(count_deposit) as cnt_depositors, sum(count_trans) as count_trans, och.name as operator_category_high, ocm.name as operator_category_medium, ocl.name as operator_category_low from 9bf92fsums s      inner join depositor_type t on s.ad_id=t.depositor_id and t.type='a'      inner join operator o on s.operator_id=o.id      left join operator_category_high och on (o.category_high_id=och.id)     left join operator_category_medium ocm on (o.category_medium_id=ocm.id)     left join operator_category_low ocl on (o.category_low_id=ocl.id) where t.amount > 0  group by ad_id, och.name, ocm.name, ocl.name

select 'MD' as type, md_id as phone, t.amount,  sum(trans_amount), sum(incoming_commission) as incoming_commission, sum(retailer_commission) as retailer_commission,  sum(ad_commission) as ad_commission, sum(md_commission) as md_commission, sum(cnf_commission), sum(count_deposit) as cnt_depositors, sum(count_trans) as count_trans, och.name as operator_category_high, ocm.name as operator_category_medium, ocl.name as operator_category_low from 9bf92fsums s      inner join depositor_type t on s.md_id=t.depositor_id and t.type='m'      inner join operator o on s.operator_id=o.id      left join operator_category_high och on (o.category_high_id=och.id)     left join operator_category_medium ocm on (o.category_medium_id=ocm.id)     left join operator_category_low ocl on (o.category_low_id=ocl.id) where t.amount > 0  group by md_id, och.name, ocm.name, ocl.name

select 'CNF' as type, cnf_id as phone, t.amount,  sum(trans_amount), sum(incoming_commission) as incoming_commission, sum(retailer_commission) as retailer_commission,  sum(ad_commission) as ad_commission, sum(md_commission) as md_commission, sum(cnf_commission), sum(count_deposit) as cnt_depositors, sum(count_trans) as count_trans, och.name as operator_category_high, ocm.name as operator_category_medium, ocl.name as operator_category_low from 9bf92fsums s      inner join depositor_type t on s.cnf_id=t.depositor_id and t.type='c'      inner join operator o on s.operator_id=o.id      left join operator_category_high och on (o.category_high_id=och.id)     left join operator_category_medium ocm on (o.category_medium_id=ocm.id)     left join operator_category_low ocl on (o.category_low_id=ocl.id) where t.amount > 0  group by cnf_id, och.name, ocm.name, ocl.name

select distinct 'no deposits' as type, null as depositor_id, 0 as sum_dep_amount,  sum(trans_amount), sum(incoming_commission) as incoming_commission, sum(retailer_commission) as retailer_commission,  sum(ad_commission) as ad_commission, sum(md_commission) as md_commission, sum(cnf_commission), 0 as cnt_depositors, sum(count_trans) as count_trans, och.name as operator_category_high, ocm.name as operator_category_medium, ocl.name as operator_category_low from 9bf92fsums s      inner join operator o on s.operator_id=o.id      left join operator_category_high och on (o.category_high_id=och.id)     left join operator_category_medium ocm on (o.category_medium_id=ocm.id)     left join operator_category_low ocl on (o.category_low_id=ocl.id) group by 'no deposits', och.name, ocm.name, ocl.name

select distinct 'no transactions' as type, depositor_id, sum(amount) as sum_dep_amount, 0 as trans_amount,  0 as incoming_commission, 0 as retailer_commission, 0 as ad_commission, 0 as md_commission, 0 as cnf_commission, count(d.id) as cnt_depositors, 0 as cnt_txn_id,  'n/a' as operator_category_high, 'n/a' as operator_category_medium, 'n/a' as operator_category_low from depositor d where  depositor_id not in (select user_rmn from 9bf92fsums)  and depositor_id not in (select ad_id from 9bf92fsums)  and depositor_id not in (select md_id from 9bf92fsums)  and depositor_id not in (select cnf_id from 9bf92fsums) group by 'no transactions', depositor_id
```

Comment: It isn't clear with just this information, how the one query may be blocking the other, assuming that's a precise description of what's happening.  The output from `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and anything relevant from the [transaction and locking information schema tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-information-schema-examples.html) would be the places to begin to develop an understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the queries, and `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

Comment: Have added information

Answer (score 1):

Rather than address the question as asked, I will address some optimizations.

- Don't mix charsets -- I see `latin1` and `utf8`.  Charset conversion can prevent usage of indexes.
- Smaller leads to faster...
- Shrink datatypes where practical -- do you really need `BIGINT` (8 bytes)?  The "operators" could probably do with `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte).  Etc.
- decimal(20,4) -- nice commission!  Up to 9999999999999999.9999; I can't think of any currency where that would not be bigger than all the money in the world.  And it takes 10 bytes.

I presume you are augmenting, not rebuilding, the "Summary tables"?  More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).  Proper use of Summary tables is the main way to get performance from "reports".

Time each statement -- perhaps one of them (the `UPDATE` with the subqueries?) is taking most of the time.

Comment: thanks good points. operators are 10 digits phone numbers, bigint seemed most efficient. currency not sure, this is rupees, probably slightly too big. Good point on charsets. also tahnsk for the summary tables link. Early days at this point. I'm still keen to understand the lockup issue, as it seems illogical o me

Comment: FYI: India GDP in rupees: 127409915349999.98, at 0.1% of gdp, I need 16 digits, which is 4+3 bytes. Certainly worth reducing it

Comment: I stand corrected.  `DECIMAL(20,4)` gives 16 digits (8 bytes) before the decimal place and 4 after (2 bytes).

Comment: Sorry, I did not spot an obvious cause for the lockup issue.

Answer (score 1):

From your output:

```
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 328780908334688, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328780908336512, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328780908335600, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328780908333776, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328780908332864, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
```

These 5 "idle" (note the quotes, the definition of an active transaction on InnoDB is obvious, you can run `START TRANSACTION` and you would not be in an active transaction until you run your first query) probably indicates one of 2: You must have gotten that output after the problem is gone **OR the problem doesn't have to do with InnoDB transaction row writes/serialization**. I would need to see `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to confirm the latter, however, based on your queries, I would suspect the issue is an old friend called [**metadata locking**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html) (which is only indirectly related to transaction processing).

Metadata locking issues (something that you can confirm by running `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, and getting a bunch of queries in "Waiting for Metadata Lock" state) happen when you execute a DDL-like statement (CREATE, DROP, etc.) and there are (long) running queries (even reads!). DDLs have to wait for all reads to finish to acquire the metadata locks, which in turn block all subsequent queries (SELECTs too).

These are strategies to mitigate these issues:

- Do not run DDLs except on low load (in particular, outside of long running transactions like analytics-like queries or backups).
- Do not drop or modify existing tables, do calculations on temporary (for your session-only) or process-exclusive tables
- Limit the amount of time a DDL can get blocked until the query fails. You can reduce that to, lets say, [lock_wait_timeout](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/28/mysql-5-5-lock_wait_timeout-patience-is-a-virtue-and-a-locked-server/) from **the default 1 year**(!), to a few seconds. We do that for online schema changes at Wikipedia: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/OSOF/browse/master/dbtools/osc_host.sh;2cd94501c64236d871a19ceec6173d3f6c5ec197$132 The query will fail, but you can capture that and try 2 or 3 times before complaining (better than creating a horrible pileup of all queries using that table). This is a very common problem- we suffer from it on the revision table of the mediawiki installation for enwiki, and we plan to roll-in some kind of partitioning to mitigate that.

Later versions of MySQL started introducing [Metadata Lock monitoring](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locks-table.html) as part of performance_schema, but it was (and is, not every body has the latest version) a pain to debug in the past. Enable P_S, if you haven't already, its 1-4% overhead is worth the amount of time spent on debugging issues blindly.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I'm afraid I can't confirm that there is any metadata locking happening. Nothing of the like in SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST. I'm on AWS RDS MySL 5.7.11 and performance_schema.meta_data_locks is empty. Still, all other tabs in my application stall until the big queries are done. Also, my DDL is in temporary tables and 9bf92fsums is randomly names for each report execution. I tried to make it temporary, but can't query against temporary tables multiple times. Creating it multiple times would take very long

Comment: I have done further testing, logging into MySQL command line, while the report is being produced. Actually there is no lock up. I can also run the application in "debug" mode in parallel and have no locking, so this issue is clearly at application level.